# Synonym for "while you're at it"

Tags: grammar

> Do this, and while you're at it, do the other.

I'd like to express this in a way that is a little more formal, "while you're at it" sounds too casual for the context I need.

An example would be: take the car and get it washed, and while you're at it, clean the interior as well.

Might anyone be able to suggest a synonym for this (while you're at it)?

Comment: 'Simultaneously' is a hypernym (if one can apply the term to non-substantives).

Comment: Thanks, but it won't do. I should have been a little more detailed in my question. "Simultaneously" implies that both activities are to be performed at the same time. I'm not concerned with the timing... you can wash the car, and AFTERWARD, clean the interior. They don't have to occur simultaneously.

Comment: Yes; 'simultaneously' isn't usually broadened to 'in the same [notional] interval of time', whereas 'while you're at it' almost invariably is. The degree of synonymity is very small if it exists at all. It's a good question, and I'm not sure there's a reasonable answer ( 'in the same [notional] interval of time' being not advisable outside analyses). // I'll leave my first comment, though I agree that 'while you're at it' usually doesn't mean 'at precisely the same time'. // Something like 'Could you also ... before you go for lunch.' is the usual work-around.

Comment: 'While you're there', 'at the same time', 'whilst that is occuring', or simply 'and'.

Comment: "At the same time" may work. Would we have a similar problem as with "simultaneously" though?

What about "utilize the occasion" ?

Comment: "while you're at it" really is more about softening the request for more additional work I think than it is about adding another task- as a justification as well as suggestion that efficiency might favor doing the both together. As @marcellothearcane mentions.. simply "and" would work fine.  To be a bit more formal, as well as solicitous, perhaps "I think it also makes sense to do the other now too please" or (as marcellothearcane also suggests -- "I'd like to have this other done at the same time")

Answer (score 1):

'**Concurrently**' works.  It includes both 'simultaneously' and 'side-by-side' or 'back-to-back'.