# "Do this, and while you're at it, do the other." Can we use "on the way" instead of "while you're at it"?

Tags: phrases

"Do this, and while you're at it, do the other." Can we use "on the way" instead of "while you're at it"? "Bring me coffee. On the way takesome candies"? Is such a sentence ok?

Comment: You can only use “on the way” when they will actually be on the way somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Synonym for "while you're at it"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395427/synonym-for-while-youre-at-it)

Comment: If you have to walk some distance to bring the coffee, you can use "on the way" to mean that you do it while walking.

Comment: But usually it would be On the way back, or On your way to the office, not just "on the way."

Comment: The literal sense is so common that care needs to be taken in using 'on the way' metaphorically.

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies. They're very much helpful 

Answer (score 1):

"While you are at it" means during the process of doing something.

"On the way" means while you are travelling somewhere.

So if you said "go and get muffins from the bake shop" you could say either "on the way drop off my dry cleaning" or "while you are at it drop off my dry cleaning".

If you said to someone already sat at their desk "edit this report" you could say "while you are doing it answer this online this survey". But it would not make sense to say "on the way answer this online survey" because they are not having to travel to edit the report.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. In the case of "edit this report", can we express the same idea with "YOU MAY AS WELL answer the online survey" instead of "while you are doing it..."?

Comment: Please ask a separate question.

Comment: If I ask a seperate new question, wouldn't it be a repetition of almost the same question as the original one? I'm simply new on this site and not sure how to use it correctly:)

Comment: No. You didn't ask about "you may as well" so it isn't a duplicate.